# JSON Theme to Center Align Values in a Table and Matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm writing a JSON theme for Power Bi but I can't get the values to center align in either the table or matrix. I was able to center align the column header but not the table. I tried implementing two things:

1. 

```
> "values": [{
>          "backColorPrimary": {"solid": {"color": "#FFFFFF"}},
>          "backColorSecondary": {"solid": {"color": "#EDEFF3"}},
>    "alignment": "Center"}]`
```

and

2.

```
>           "Specific column": [{
>       "alignment": "Center"}]
```

neither work. Any help is much appreciated!!

[image: Code]

Comment: Currently not supported - I suspect it may never will, as alignment is auto-dependant on the data-type.